# Is there any functional difference between по- and попо- prefixes, as in "попоїсти"?

Tags: дієслова, префікс, verb-prefixes

According to the dictionaries, they both denote *perfective mood* of the verbs:

> ***по***їсти vs. ***попо***їсти,
>   ***по***ходити vs. ***попо***ходити

…and so on.

Do these prefixes have equivalent function, or is there any difference?
If there is any, how do I choose which one to use?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As a matter of fact, there is a difference.

Verbs starting with a prefix "`попо-`" are called **iterative verbs** (denoting **repeated action**).

It's notable that **perfective iterative verbs** (*попоходити, попоносити, попобити, попоплакати, попостогнати* тощо) are **distinctive for the Ukrainian language**.

> Так, ітеративні дієслова доконаного виду (*попоходити, попоносити*)
>   властиві тільки українській мові, ітеративні дієслова недоконаного
>   виду — російській (стилістично обмежені утворення типу *хаживать,
>   говаривать, нашивать*) та чеській (*chodivat, chodivavat*) мовам,
>   дистрибутивні дієслова доконаного виду з двома префіксами частіше або
>   рідше вживаються у всіх слов'янських мовах, однак найбільшого
>   поширення ці утворення набули в польській та українській мовах.
>
> ...
>
> Оригінальним українським утворенням є багатократні (ітеративні)
>   дієслова, що виражають значення виконуваної з напруженням і
>   повторюваної дії. Цей [рід дієсловної дії] утворюється за допомогою префікса попо-,
>   тобто редуплікованого префікса по- (*попоходити, попотягати,
>   поповодити* і под.), напр.: *«Як вигнала мене свекруха... що я
>   попотужила» (Ганна Барвінок); «Ото попоходиш за плугом, попотягаєш
>   чепіги, то й, зрозуміло, втома бере своє» (О. Ковінька); «Бідолаха
>   попокланявся, задкуючи до фургона, просто не вірив, що його
>   відпускають» (О. Гончар).*

Source: [Граматика української мови ДІЄСЛОВО 6. ГРАМАТИЧНІ КАТЕГОРІЇ ДІЄСЛОВА Категорія родів дії](http://subject.com.ua/ukrmova/gramatica/66.html)

Nonetheless, there is a small group of **imperfective iterative verbs** in Ukrainian, with suffixes `-ва-`, `-а-`: *бувати (до бути), живати (до жити), знавати (до знати), пивати (до пити), чувати (до чути), видати (до видіти), їдати (до їсти), їжджати (до їздити)*

Source: [Wikipedia](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%96_%D0%B4%D1%96%D1%94%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0)

It's notable, that prefex `"попо-"` may be added to the verbs echoing animals, birds, insects sounds, but those are mostly used in spoken language, rather informal, and are not included into dictionaries (*собака поповив, кішка попонявкала, мухи поподзижчали* тощо).

> Слід  зауважити,  що  префікс  попо‐  може приєднуватися і до дієслів,
>   що відтворюють звукові вияви тварин, птахів, комах тощо, але похідні
>   від них префіксальні дієслова з ітеративним значенням вживаються
>   переважно в усно‐розмовному мовленні,  через що  не  подаються  у 
>   словниках,  пор.  такі  вживання:  С*обака  поповив  уночі;  Кішка
>   попонявкала  під  дверима;  Ця  курка  попосокотала  вранці;  Жаби 
>   попоквакали  перед  дощем;  Кіт попомурчав,  лежачи  біля  теплої 
>   грубки;  Корова  попомукала  в  повітці;  Мухи  поподзижчали  на шибках
>   вікон*.

Source: [Видові особливості дієслів лексико-семантичної групи зі значенням звучання Чубань, Т.В. ; Левченко, Т.М.](http://litmisto.org.ua/?p=26051)

Thus, if one describes **non-repeated action** then **non-iterative** (ordinary) verb should be used, with `"по-"` prefix (*поїсти, попити, потужити, побити*), and for **repeated (recurrent) action** **iterative verb** is preferrable, with `"попо-"` prefix (*попоїсти, попопити, попотужити, попобити*).

**Hint: repeated action - repeated prefix.**

Comment: Interesting, whether this use of `попо-` introduces some ambiguity - `Повитуха поповила уночі`, although it must be rare, and context-dependent.

Comment: @SassaNF as a matter of fact it's only at the fist sight. Upon more thorough analysis it becomes clear that there is no ambiguity. *Повитуха поповила* means *повитуха попоплакала/попотужила*  (from **вити - to cry**). Iterative from **повити - to swaddle** should be *попоповила* then, shouldn't it? And the main aim to use iterative form - is to show repeated action while it seems hardly possible that a doula might swaddle more than one or two babies during one night)

Comment: No, I meant that `поповила` as not iterative perfective from `повила` vs iterative perfective from `вила`.

Comment: @SassaNF it's an interesing case indeed. Though I agree it may rarely occur. And by the way, imho, non-iterative perfective from *"повила"* should be *"повила"* itself (unlike *повивала* for imperfective) or *"сповила"* which is even better as to my ear.

Comment: Agreed, `сповила` sounds way better. Maybe `поповила` doesn't even exist as a normative word.

Comment: Т. Г.Шевченко ["Сон"](http://litopys.org.ua/shevchenko/shev2116.htm) "...На сина глянула, взяла,
Його тихенько сповила
Та, щоб дожать до ланового,
Ще копу дожинать пішла."