# Що не так з "почекуном"?

Tags: вживання-слів, росіянізм, неологізми, віддієслівні-іменники

Назва нового мему з [*Почекуном*](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%96%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BD) була скалькована з російського *Ждун*, який в свою чергу був утворений від <sub>рос.</sub> *ждать* (одразу завважу, що я не обговорюю тут власне *Ждуна*, хоча знаю, що в українській мові також є [*ждати*](http://sum.in.ua/s/zhdaty)).

Стаття на вікі про [суфіксальне словоутворення віддієслівних іменників](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%83%D1%84%D1%96%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F#.D0.A1.D0.BB.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.BE.D1.82.D0.B2.D1.96.D1.80.D0.BD.D1.96_.D1.82.D0.B8.D0.BF.D0.B8_.D0.BD.D0.B0.D0.B7.D0.B2_.D0.BE.D1.81.D1.96.D0.B1) вказує весь набір суфіксів, але не подає правило, за яким той чи інший суфікс має допасовуватися до дієслова. Звідки я роблю висновок, що єдине правило — правило милозвучності.

Питання моє в тому, чи виглядає "питомим" поточне словотворення від дієслова [*почекати*](http://sum.in.ua/s/pochekaty)?

Нижче я подаю деякі можливі варіянти:

1. Почека́ль / Почека́ля (також див. [*чекальний*](http://sum.in.ua/s/chekaljnyj))
2. Почека́ч
3. Почека́р
4. Почеку́н (також допустимо, бо [*бігун*](http://sum.in.ua/s/bighun))
5. Почеківни́к
6. Почекі́ст (sic!)
7. Почека́тель

Одному мені здається, що варіянти 1-2 звучать "рідніше" і що суфіксальне словоутворення теж було бездумно скальковане?

Comment: [Чекайло](//www.facebook.com/Nehrebeckyj/posts/1390996047631492?comment_id=1391048180959612&comment_tracking=%7B%22tn%22%3A%22R9%22%7D), [чекун](http://goloskarpat.info/society/588f39a87b5c8/), чекач, чек(айло/аль/аля/ар/атель/івський), **за**чек(айло/аль/аля/ар/атель/ач/івський/іст/ун).

Comment: А чим просте _ждан_ не підходить?

Comment: @YellowSky це вже інше, тут я щодо суфіксів (і префіксів) запитував

Comment: [За]чекайло, на мою думку, найліпше.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Перше.** Я вважаю, що, оскільки цей інтернет-мем прийшов до нас із російськомовної інтернет-спільноти, то і назва має право (хоча і не зобов'язана) бути також запозиченою з російської, попри те, що сама скульптура створена нідерландським майстром.

**Друге**. Назва.

Доцільно розглянути морфологічну послідовність з російської мови:

<sub>рос.</sub> *прыгать → прыгун → попрыгун*

1. Перше слово — це дієслово недоконаного виду, семантичний зміст якого також визначає деяку **дію** (бездіяльність — це також, у деякому сенсі, дія).
   Український еквівалент, вочевидь, — [**стрибати**](http://sum.in.ua/s/strybaty).
2. Друге слово — професійно-якісний віддієслівний іменник, який означає особу, яка **постійно/професійно виконує зазначену дію**.
   Український еквівалент — [**стрибун**](http://sum.in.ua/s/strybun):

   > 1. Людина, яка робить стрибок, стрибки, любить стрибати;

   Також див. [**плигун**](http://sum.in.ua/s/plyghun).
3. Третє слово утворене із попереднього, [морфологічний зміст](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/507/) префікса `по-` — недоконаність та повторюваність дії. Український еквівалент — [**пострибун**](http://sum.in.ua/s/postrybun):

   > Той, хто часто стрибає, не сидить спокійно на місці;

---

Висновок: **почекун** (а також, спірно, **чекун** і **попочекун**) цілком можна вважати питомими словами, які не суперечать типовій українській морфології.

З іншого боку, їх не можна вважати нормативними (усталеними), оскільки вони не згадуються у словниках.

Answer (score 1):

[Норми української літературної мови](https://r2u.org.ua/guides/synyavsky/slovotvir_narostky) · [Олекса Синявський](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%9E%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0_%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87)

> § 99. Наростки іменникові: значіння їх і вживання
>
> **87.** **‑ун** — на означення носія певної чинности або властивости (здебільшого особи і з відтінком зневаги): *брехун*, *балакун*, *їздун*, *свистун*, *шептун*, *мовчун*, *літун*, *гордун*, *щебетун*, *ласун*, *цвіркун*, *двигун*… (*порівн.* **‑ій**, **‑ак**).

Comment: І який висновок?

Comment: @Sasha Я подав правило. Цитую запитавця: _Стаття на вікі про суфіксальне словоутворення віддієслівних іменників вказує весь набір суфіксів, але не подає правило, за яким той чи інший суфікс має допасовуватися до дієслова_. Також підвердив, що такий наросток цілком існує.