# Чи є пасивні дієслівні конструкції питомими для української мови?

Tags: вживання-слів

Сьогодні у новинах читаю: [У Харкові **очікується** похолодання і дощ](http://www.slk.kh.ua/news/suspilstvo/kharkovi-ochikuyetsya-pogirshennya-pogodi.html).

Тлумачні словники, що я бачив, дають однакове значення активним (*ми очікуємо*) і пасивним зворотам (*очікується*).

Інші ж, такі, як СУМ, взагалі вважають основною формою *явно запозичене «ждати»*:
[очікуватися](http://sum.in.ua/s/ochikuvatysja) = ждатися = «Передбачатися в майбутньому» (причому навіть словник використовує пасивну форму «передбачати**ся**» замість «хтось передбачає в майбутньому»),
[очікувати](http://sum.in.ua/s/ochikuvaty) = ждати = «Розраховувати на чиє-небудь повернення, на прихід, появу когось, чогось, на здійснення чогось»

Мені здається, що пасивні, безособові звороти прийшли до нас з іноземної мови, де панує ідеологія відмови від відповідальності, і завдяки цьому у місцевому канцеляриті утворилися конструкції:
«вашу заяву *{буде} розглянуто*»
проти
«*я розгляну{в}* вашу заяву» або «*оцей чиновник розгляне{-ув}* вашу заяву».

Запитання: наскільки питомим є використання саме **пасивного звороту** у контексті подій, які передбачають**ся** у майбутньому?

P.S. У нас вже було запитання на тему «ждати/чекати», але там цю тему не зрушували: 
[Що не так з "почекуном"?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/691/%d0%a9%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc)

P.P.S. У тому числі, на нашому сайті при обговоренні граматичних правил, багато користувачів також використовують звороти:

- *у випадку Х кома **не ставиться***
- *через дефіс **пишеться** у випадку Y*

Comment: Вас цікавлять лише синтетичні форми з _-ся_ (_пишеться_) чи конструкції _бути_ + _пасивний дієприкметник минулого часу_ (_була написана_) теж цікавлять?

Comment: @YellowSky, думаю, що усі випадки пасивних конструкцій, окрім «легітимних» як-то *«молодята кохаються»*, *«гори видніються»*, або *«книгу було написано у N році»*. Тобто, усі випадки, коли пасивну конструкцію легко замінити на активну.

Comment: Вибачте, та я не дуже розумію, які конструкції «легітимні», а які ні, де їх легко замінити, а де ні… «Молодята кохаються», «гори видніються» — це ж не пасивні конструкції, там просто зворотні дієслова, й вони неперехідні, а неперехідні дієслова в українській не можуть мати пасивного стану.

Comment: «Пишеться» [вживали](http://search2.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?mycorp=(lang%3A%22ukr%22%20%7C%20lang_trans%3A%22ukr%22)&mysent=&mysize=9383924&mysentsize=919437&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=para&sort=gr_tagging&env=alpha&req=%EF%E8%F8%E5%F2%FC%F1%FF&p=1) й Леся Українка, й Квітка-Основ’яненко, й Панас Мирний.

Comment: @YellowSky, я саме тому і запитав, що не знаю, де провести межу між обґрунтованим використанням і канцеляритом.

Comment: Кропивницький [вживав](http://search2.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?mycorp=%28lang%3A%22ukr%22+%7C+lang_trans%3A%22ukr%22%29&mysent=&mysize=9383924&mysentsize=919437&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=para&sort=gr_tagging&env=alpha&req=%E6%E4%E5%F2%FC%F1%FF) «ждеться». «Ждати» [вживали](http://search2.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?mycorp=(lang%3A%22ukr%22%20%7C%20lang_trans%3A%22ukr%22)&mysent=&mysize=9383924&mysentsize=919437&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=para&sort=gr_tagging&env=alpha&req=%E6%E4%E0%F2%E8&p=2) Стефаник, Коцюбинський, Винниченко, Леся Українка, Ольга Кобилянська, Марко Черемшина, тощо.

Comment: @bytebuster, ось є така стаття Олени Лаврінець [ПАСИВНІ КОНСТРУКЦІЇ З ДІЄСЛОВАМИ НА -СЯ В СУЧАСНІЙ НАУКОВІЙ МОВІ: СИНОНІМІЯ ТА ПАРАЛЕЛІЗМ ФУНКЦІОНУВАННЯ](https://www.google.com.ua/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj-0c6P8oPUAhXLkCwKHetCB_oQFgg9MAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Firbis-nbuv.gov.ua%2Fcgi-bin%2Firbis_nbuv%2Fcgiirbis_64.exe%3FC21COM%3D2%26I21DBN%3DUJRN%26P21DBN%3DUJRN%26IMAGE_FILE_DOWNLOAD%3D1%26Image_file_name%3DPDF%2FUkrm_2014_1_8.pdf&usg=AFQjCNHgUKWi6Y_bu_Yfq3eac-BA7MnR7Q&sig2=e0KZ6--GAEOmNVACgUvlZA) з проблематики, що Вас цікавить.

Comment: @OksanaGubrenko, цікаво, дякую. Щоправда, наукова мова — це трошки особлива галузь. *«Ряд збігається»* або *«функція інтегрується»* — це нормально, бо це не хтось її інтегрує, а функція має властивість інтегровності. А от *«погода очікується»* — це не те саме. Це не властивість погоди, а властивість науковця-синоптика. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Складно давати стислі відповіді на такі осяжні запитання. Утім, спробую.

Багато фахівців досліджує проблематику надмірного і почасти невиправданого вживання пасивних дієслівних конструкцій саме в наукових, фахових текстах, діловій мові. Проте, на мою думку, більшість із висновків можна екстраполювати і на звичайну мову.

Відносно стисло й доступно для широкого загалу викладено в [Методичних вказівках до виконання практичних робіт з дисципліни «Українська мова (за професійним спрямуванням)» (для студентів усіх курсів та напрямів підготовки) ДНТУ](http://www.studfiles.ru/preview/5679501/page:13/):

> **Активні та пасивні дієслівні конструкції**
>
> Книжному стилю російської мови притаманно широко вживати три
>   компонентні пасивні конструкції, утворені дієсловом недоконаного виду
>   пасивного стану на `–ся`: *сообщения распространяются средствами
>   массовой информации; нашим коллективом выполняется ответственное
>   задание; нами проводились многочисленные исследования; оппоненты
>   назначаются Ученым советом; эта проблема рассматривалась многими
>   ученими* тощо. Для всіх цих речень характерно, що іменник (займенник)
>   у формі орудного відмінка (*средствами, коллективом, нами, советом,
>   учеными*) позначає активного виконавця дії, а об’єкт дії (*сообщения,
>   задание, оппоненты, проблема*) подано іменником у називному відмінку,
>   тобто виконавець дії стає додатком, а об’єкт дії – підметом.
>   Граматично присудок описує дію підмета, спрямовану на додаток, а для
>   того, щоб показати протилежний напрямок дії, у наведених реченнях
>   вжито зворотну форму дієслова-присудка.
>
> **В українському реченні виконавець дії – це підмет, об’єкт дії – додаток, а присудок описує дію підмета на додаток, і його, як правило,
>   подають дієсловом 3-ї особи однини або множини.**
>
> Отже, для наведених російських речень українські відповідники будуть
>   такі: *Засоби масової інформації розповсюджують повідомлення*. *Наш
>   колектив виконує відповідальне завдання*. *Ми проводили численні
>   дослідження*. *Опонентів призначає Вчена рада* або *Учена рада
>   призначає опонентів*. *Ця проблема цікавила багатьох учених* або
>   *Багато вчених вивчало цю проблему*.
>
> **Аналогічно не слід уживати зворотні дієслова у підрядних реченнях**: *Компьютер, характеризующийся малыми размерами*. – *Комп’ютер, якого характеризують невеликі розміри* або *Комп’ютер, для якого характерні
>   невеликі розміри*. *Исследование, осуществляемое экспертом*. –
>   *Дослідження, що його проводить експерт*.
>
> З наведених рекомендацій не слід робити хибний висновок, ніби
>   зворотних дієслів на `–ся` треба взагалі уникати.
>
> **Зворотні дієслова слід уживати в таких реченнях, коли**:
>
> а) **дія спрямована на самого суб’єкта дії**: *голитися, митися,
>   одягатися*;
>
> б) **дія є взаємо-зворотною**: *листуватися, змагатися, обніматися,
>   миритися*;
>
> в) **дію особа виконує в своїх інтересах**: *будуватися, пакуватися*;
>
> г) **дія називає типові ознаки самого суб’єкта**: *собака кусається,
>   папір рветься, скло б’ється*.
>
> **Крім зворотних дієслів на `–ся`, є ще група безособових дієслів:** *не спиться, не лежиться, не хочеться, не віриться*. **Такі дієслова мають лише форму третьої особи однини**.
>
> Виходячи з вище викладеного, фраза: *Вітер швидко змінюється* – цілком
>   правильна, бо підмет вітер є водночас суб’єктом і об’єктом дії. А
>   речення: *Двері відчиняються водієм* – ненормативне (хіба що «пхнули»
>   водія і так відчинили двері). Інша річ, коли форму орудного відмінка
>   має назва предмета, за допомогою якого виконують дію. Тому фраза
>   *Двері відчиняться оцим ключем* відповідає нормі, бо ключ – знаряддя дії, за допомогою якого двері може відчинити неназвана в реченні особа
>   (суб’єкт дії). Хоча, на думку науковців, краще цю думку висловити так:
>   *Двері відчиняють оцим ключем*.
>
> Отже, **залежно від характеру дії слід уживати різні конструкції**:
>   *Он изменяется (деформируется, нагревается) кем-то, чем-то*. – *Його змінює (деформує, нагріває) хтось, щось* (**пасивна дія**). *Он
>   изменяется (деформируется, нагревается) где-то (при каких-то
>   условиях)*. – *Він змінюється (деформується, нагрівається) десь (за
>   певних умов)* (**неперехідна дія**).
>
> У навчальних, науково-технічних та офіційно-ділових текстах часто
>   зловживають пасивними конструкціями з дієсловами на `–ся`, у яких
>   об’єкт, на який спрямована дія, подано у формі називного відмінка, а
>   назви суб’єкта дії немає, наприклад, *формула береться в дужки,
>   видання друкувалися, якість гарантується*.
>
> **У цих конструкціях природніше вживати особові форми дієслова**: *В конце предложения ставится точка. – Наприкінці речення ставлять
>   крапку* або *Наприкінці речення ставимо крапку*. *Большая буква
>   пишется в следующих случаях. – Велику літеру пишуть у таких випадках*
>   або *Велику літеру пишемо у таких випадках. Машина испытывается в
>   лаборатории. – Машину випробовують у лабораторії*.
>
> Конструкції з дієсловами у формі третьої особи множини (*ставлять,
>   пишуть, випробують*) надають реченню більш загального (безособового)
>   відтінку, тоді як форму першої особи краще вживати у
>   навчально-методичній літературі, бо вони підкреслюють спільність дій
>   викладача (інструктора) й учня (студента, слухача).

Окремо слід згадати про безособові форми на `-но`, `-то`, які окремі фахівці теж відносять до форм пасивного стану.

> **Вживання безособових конструкцій на -но, -то.**
>
> **В українській мові для позначання дії, яка не передбачає точного означення її виконавця, уживають безособові конструкції з
>   віддієприкметниковими формами на `-но`, `-то`, які використовують у
>   діловому стилі від XIV ст. і які становлять національну специфіку
>   української мови:** *Нове рішення вироблено згідно з обставинами*.
>
> **Безособові конструкції на `-но`, `-то` керують іменником у знахідному відмінку без прийменника:** *вироблено (що?) новий підхід
>   (нове рішення, нову методику)*.
>
> Уживаючи безособові конструкції, автори часто-густо допускають
>   помилку, уводячи в речення виконавця дії у формі іменника чи
>   займен­ника в орудному відмінку. Не можна писати *Комісією вироблено
>   нове рішення згідно з обставинами*, бо в цьому реченні є виконавець
>   дії – комісія, причому це слово стоїть у орудному відмінку. Тому
>   наведена конструкція є помилковою, її необхідно перебудувати так:
>   *Комісія виробила нове рішення згідно з обставинами*.
>
> В орудному відмінку може стояти іменник (займенник), що означає
>   знаряддя дії. Правильно писати *Лист написано олівцем*, бо олівець –
>   це знаряддя дії, але неправильно *Лист написано хлопцем* (у цьому
>   прикладі треба вжити активну конструкцію *Хлопець написав листа*).
>
> **Отже, безособову форму дієслова на `-но`, `-то` можна вживати лише у реченнях, де явно не зазначено виконавця дії.**
>
> **Форми на `-но`, `-то` надають реченню певного відтінку минулості і доконаності. Тому їх зазвичай уживають без допоміжного дієслова
>   `було`:** *одержано результати, проведено дослід, машину випробувано,
>   якість гарантовано*.
>
> Конструкції з допоміжним словом було вживають зрідка, коли
>   підкреслюють, що одна минула дія відбулася перед іншою минулою дією:
>   *деталь було нагріто у печі, а потім занурено у воду.* У вислові *книгу буде написано* підкреслено, що дія обов’язково відбудеться і завершиться в майбутньому (доконаність дії в майбутньому). Між
>   висловами *якість гарантовано* та *якість гарантуємо* є певна
>   стилістична різниця: перший вислів підкреслює, що вже (у минулому)
>   хтось ужив заходів, щоб забезпечити якість, а в другому підкреслено,
>   що необхідні заходи ми продовжуємо вживати ще й зараз.

Тому, хто бажає глибше зануритися в проблематику, пропоную прочитати такі матеріали:

- [Пасивні форми в сучасних літературних українській та польській мовах (реферат)](http://5ka.at.ua/load/movoznavstvo/pasivni_formi_v_suchasnikh_literaturnikh_ukrajinskij_ta_polskij_movakh_referat/41-1-0-6837)
- [Співвідношення активних і пасивних конструкцій у наукових текстах (Посібник з української мови)](http://posibnyky.vntu.edu.ua/u_m/5.htm)
- [Олена Курило: Уваги до сучасної української літературної мови](http://kurylo.wikidot.com/3-nevlastyva-ukrainskii-movi-konstruktsiia:pasyvnyi-predykat)
- [Михайло Гінзбург: Синтаксичні конструкції у фахових текстах: практичні висновки з рекомендацій мовознавців](http://tc.terminology.lp.edu.ua/TK_Wisnyk620/TK_wisnyk620_ginzburg.htm)
- [Петрович Л. І.: Уживання активних та пасивних форм дієслів в українській фаховій мові](http://eir.nuos.edu.ua/xmlui/bitstream/handle/123456789/1508/Petrovich.pdf?sequence=1)
- [З. Й. Куньч: Уникання пасивних дієслівних конструкцій як елемент культури української мови](https://ukrsense.dp.ua/index.php/USENSE/article/view/18)