# Коли правильно вживати "пов'язано", а коли "пов'язане"

Tags: різниця-між-словами, дієприкметники

Наскільки я розумію, для цього є якесь правило. Але не знаю, як краще знайти. Чи "пов'язано" це калька з російської "связано"?

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до сайту Ukrainian Language.SE! Будь ласка, наведіть кілька прикладів речень, у яких ви підшукуєте правильне слово. Контекст — це завжди важливо, його завжди варто вказувати, інакше читачам доводиться вгадувати.

Comment: Перепрошую, але навіщо контекст з прикладами _декількох_речень_? - мене цікавить правило, не тільки конкретний приклад. Приклад може бути простий: "прізвище пов'язано з словом" - це результат роботи Google Translate. Інші приклади можна знайти пошуком, https://www.google.com/#q=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%27%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%27%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5

Comment: Не існує жодного правила стосовно конкретного слова «повʼязано». Існують правила використання відмінків дієприкметників у конкретних ситуаціях. Контекст — це і є ситуація. А стосовно пошуку — не варто змушувати робити інших вашу роботу. :-)

Comment: "правила використання відмінків дієприкметників у конкретних ситуаціях." - так наведіть їх, і не треба розводити цирк. Один приклад в вас був.

Comment: @user236360 [пов'язано](http://sum.in.ua/s/pov.jazanyj) - це [безособове дієслово](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Безособові_форми_на_-но,_-то). FYI: http://mova.ga/notes/928/bezosobovi-rechennya-na-no-to-yih-znachen

Comment: @idolon дякую! - чи означає це, що _“пов'язане”_ це помилка?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Коротко за мотивами [коментаря Idolon](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/1486#comment3967_1486) (дуже дякую, Idolon).

#### Правило

- «Пов'язан**е**» (а також «пов'язан**ий**», «пов'язан**а**», «пов'язан**і**» для інших родів і множини) — коли це слово є означенням або присудком-у-двоскладному-реченні (тобто присудком у реченні з підметом):

  - > Це правило пов'язан**е** із нормами людського суспільства. <sub>(«Правило» — підмет, «[є] пов'язане» виконує роль присудка.)</sub>
  - > І про пов'язан**е** з аварією відключення світла всі також забули. <sub>(«Пов'язане» — означення при слові «відключення».)</sub>
- «Пов'язан**о**» (в будь-якому роді) — коли це слово є присудком у односкладному (безособовому) реченні:

  - > І після цього ганчірку знов було пов'язан**о** на старе дерево. <sub>(«[Було] пов'язано» — присудок, синонім до «[якісь люди] пов'язали»; а «ганчірка» тут додаток, а не підмет.)</sub>

#### Як можна перевірити

В конкретному випадку, якщо сумніваєтеся, спробуйте змінити рід іменника, до якого стосується «пов'язан{е,о}» (підставити інший іменник). Якщо в чоловічому роді, жіночому роді чи множині природним стане «пов'язаний», «пов'язана» чи «пов'язані» — то значить в середньому має бути «пов'язане»; якщо ж у чоловічому роді, жіночому роді чи множині природним буде «пов'язано» (або ж «його/її/їх пов'язали»), то і в середньому має бути «пов'язано» (або ж «його пов'язали»).

Наприклад:

> Ця вимога пов'язана із нормами людського суспільства. <sub>(Отже і «це правило пов'язане».)</sub>
>   І про пов'язані з аварією перебої світла всі також забули. <sub>(Отже і «пов'язане відключення».)</sub>
>   І після цього папірець знов було пов'язано на старе дерево. <sub>(Отже і «папірець пов'язано».)</sub>

#### Не завжди однозначно

В багатьох випадках можна сказати і так, і так — хоч це може вимагати змін форм інших членів речення й іноді спричинить зміну конотацій:

> Ця вимога пов'язана (це правило пов'язане) із нормами людського суспільства. <sub>(Скоріше за все, вона/воно за природою своєю пов'язана/пов'язане.)</sub>
>   Цю вимогу (це правило) пов'язано (пов'язали) із нормами людського суспільства. <sub>(Скоріше за все, її/його вже потім пов'язали люди під час вивчення.)</sub>

Comment: Прошу! Дякую, що розгорнули у відповідь.

Comment: @user236360, до відповіді додам, що форми на *-но/-то* фахівці радять уживати з певними застереженнями. Розлогіше - див. [Чи є пасивні дієслівні конструкції питомими для української мови?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/1220/%D0%A7%D0%B8-%D1%94-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%96-%D0%B4%D1%96%D1%94%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%96-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%86%D1%96%D1%97-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8/1440#1440)

Comment: Дякую, @OksanaGubrenko ! :)