# Чи доречно вживати безособові форми на -но, -то?

Tags: стилістика

*Зроблено, сказано, написано…* Ці конструкції, згідно правил української мови, вживати можна. Але досвідчені філологи, редактори і коректори не рекомендують цього робити і пояснюють, що саме по собі нічого не може бути *зробле**но***. За цією дією закріплена або людина, або підприємство, приміром, які виконують певні дії, тому треба казати *„хтось“ зробив, сказав, написав*…

Невже застосування безособової форми на **‑но**, **‑то** можуть визнати помилкою?

Comment: Різні тексти зозраховуються на різну авдиторію, тому пересічному громадянинові не важливо, хто заборонив прохід, коли він бачить напис «прохід заборонено», а от у юридичних документах навпаки, важливо знати виконавця / ініціятора дії. Просто різні стилі мовлення.

Comment: Related: [“Чи є пасивні дієслівні конструкції питомими для української мови?”](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/1220)

Comment: Даӱ змогу зробити відповідь: https://r2u.org.ua/node/219

Answer (score 2):

Вживати безособові форми на -но, -то можна і це може бути цілком доречно. Я також знайшов інформацію, яка викликала у вас сумніви, а саме:

> Дієслівні форми на -но, -то називають дію, виконану невідомою або
>   неназваною особою (суб'єктом). Утім, у багатьох випадках у реченнях з
>   цими формами називають і суб'єкта (виконавця) дії в орудному відмінку.
>   Граматично такий суб'єкт у реченні виступає в ролі додатка. Наприклад,
>   **Наказ підписано директором**. Суб'єкт дії в орудному відмінку; **Дорогу
>   заасфальтовано робітниками**. Таким чином, у наведених прикладах названо
>   дійову особу, хоч граматично й виражену додатком. Низка вітчизняних
>   мовознавців, зокрема Олена Курило, вказують на неприродність подібних
>   пасивних синтаксичних конструкцій для сучасної української
>   літературної мови та рекомендують замість них уживати активні. Олена
>   Курило зауважує, що ці форми граматично безпідметові, у них взагалі
>   немає дієвої особи, вони виражають питання хтось зробив, але цей хтось
>   неназваний, невідомий. Тому, зазначає вчений, «інструменталь дієвої
>   особи тут зайвий і з логічних причин неможливий». Тут не може бути
>   питання ким? Тому такі конструкції науковці рекомендують заміняти на
>   активні з підметом, вираженим іменником у називному відмінку,
>   присудком у формі особового дієслова і додатка у формі знахідного:
>   **Директор підписав наказ**; **Робітники заасфальтували дорогу**.

Тобто, коли у нас в реченні вказується хто виконав дію, то краще використовувати активну синтаксичну конструкцію. Але, якщо ж особа відсутня, то можна використовувати форми на -но, -то, наприклад: "**Чоловіка вбито ножем**", "**Вікно розбито камнем**" - і також з цього прикладу видно, що називати знаряддя дії у таких реченнях ми теж можемо (джерело — [стаття «Безособові форми на -но, -то» у Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8_%D0%BD%D0%B0_-%D0%BD%D0%BE,_-%D1%82%D0%BE)).

Крім того, врахуйте ще що (джерело — [С. В. Шевчук, І. В. Клименко «Українська мова за професійним спрямуванням. Підручник» (К., «Алерта», 2011), § 3.3.5, с. 618](https://studfiles.net/preview/5187118/page:29/)):

> Дієслівні форми на -но,-то не можна вживати, коли з логічних причин
>   узагалі не може бути діяча. Наприклад: Дослідники збирали зразки диких
>   рослин, якими вкрито цілинний степ (**неправильно**) -Дослідники збирали
>   зразки диких рослин, якими вкритий цілинний степ (**правильно**).

Загалом, можна зробити висновок, що:

> У наукових і фахових текстах треба усувати не властиві українській
>   мові пасивні конструкції, заміняючи їх, де це можливо, на активні

Однак, є випадки, коли вживання форм на -но, -то цілком можливе і не суперечить правилам української мови.