# Ну то -ся чи не -ся?

Tags: дієслова

Використання зворотних дієслів інколи суперечить логіці.

Наприклад, [знаходитися](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8F).

> Ганна все копалась у комоді .. Хустка все чомусь не знаходилася, а
>   Гордія брала нетерплячка.

В мене постає питання: чи може хустка знаходити себе? Та наче ні. На мою думку правильніше сказати: Хустку все чомусь не знайде.

> Він знав: рано чи пізно уран знайдеться. В цьому переконувала його
>   інженерна логіка.

Як уран може себе знайти? Але ж зрозуміліше: рано чи пізно уран знайдуть.

... і так далі.

Для мене це логічна помилка, яку мені важко зрозуміти. Розумію, що в якийсь певний час просто почали так говорити.

Але логічно: "я знаходжуся", "ми знайдемося".|

Читав [таке](https://pidruchniki.com/68687/dokumentoznavstvo/zvorotni_diyeslova), де сухо кажуть, що так воно є без пояснення: чому так? Тобто вказують, що треба так використовувати. Знайшов [ЖЕЛЕХІВКУ](http://litopys.org.ua/ukrmova/um17.htm), де вже зрозуміліше пояснюють значення, що ся писали раніше окремо. А також знаходив десь те, що -ся означає себе, що й привело мене до нелогічності.

Можливо хтось знає і може дати тексти щодо значення закінчення -ся, які пояснюють подібні речі детальніше або якось інакше, зрозуміліше?

---

*Якби менше читав, то й питань подібних не було б. Одним словом халепа.*

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> *дати тексти щодо значення закінчення -ся, які пояснюють подібні речі детальніше або якось інакше, зрозуміліше?*

#### Коротка відповідь

Первісним значенням показника `-ся` є показувати відсутність/неможливість об'єкта при дії, отже, він характеризував ті дії, які відбуваються в самій дійовій особі (= *дієслово* + «себе»).

Проте, з плином часу `-ся` стало використовуватися для інших функціональних потреб. У багатьох типах дієслова показник `-ся` набрав зовсім своєрідного відтінку, що спричинилося до того, що **його загальне значення в мові сильно затерлося і вневиразнилося**.

Зважаючи на цю ситуацію, деякі науковці починають замість терміна **«зворотні дієслова»** використовувати більш загальний термін **«слова з дєслівним показником `-ся`»** (¹ ²).

#### Багато букв

1. Первісним значенням показника `-ся` є показувати відсутність/неможливість об'єкта при дії, отже, він характеризував ті **дії, які відбуваються в самій дійовій особі**

   > Тоді Дема *кидається* до столу (*кидає* вимагало б об'єкта дії, *кидається* показує, що дія безпосередньо заторкує тільки діяча)
2. Якщо дійових осіб кілька, то така дія, стосуючися до всіх, може **набирати характеру взаємности**

   > Аж тоді згодився — *поляпалися* ми долонями й *поцілувались* (один одного поляпали й поцілували)
3. Вказано лише обʼєкт (це не те саме, що випадок №1, де вказано лише субʼєкт)

   > Тут в давні дні *гострилися* мечі
4. Дієслова, що без `-ся` взагалі тепер не вживаються

   > намагатися, старатися, боятися, прокинутися, сподіватися, сумніватися

   Багато з дієслів такого типу мають більш або менш близькі синоніми без показника `-ся`:

   > дивитися — глядіти, сміятися — реготати, скаржитися — оскаржувати, знущатися — глузувати, тинятися — блукати.

   В таких обставинах природно, що особливе значення `-ся` в цих дієсловах майже зовсім затерте.
5. Показник `-ся` використовується як словотворчий елемент при витворенні внутрішньо-видових відтінків у сполуці з приростками `на-`, `ви-`, `з-` і `роз-`

   > їсти — наїстися, роз'їстися; ходити — находитися, сходитися, розходитися; говорити — наговоритися, виговоритися.

   > За дві години вони наговорилися й насперечалися досхочу

   Дієслова такого типу теж здебільшого без `-ся` не виступають або мають зовсім інше значення (порівняйте *сходив — сходився*). Це, як і сам факт використання `-ся` в ролі видового показника, теж сприяє затьмаренню його первісного значення.
6. Показник `-ся` використовується для перетворення дієслова на безособове

   > він хоче — йому хочеться, він співає — йому співається
7. В деяких випадках уживання `-ся` стає більш або менш довільним, як це можна показати на низці прикладів, де однаково легко могли б бути вжиті дієслова з показником `-ся` і без нього (різниця зазвичай лише стилістична)

   > Про все на світі я *забувся* і вслід йому дививсь
   > — Мене оставиш? — *спитався* Низа Евріял
   > Ти *обіщалась* мене вік любити
   > Місі захлипав і *запросився* пощади
   > Регіт вибухнув і гучно *покотив* з амфітеатру по коридору
   > То сяк то так на свою країну *доплентала*
   > Вже сонце *клонило* до лісу
   > Так тихо в кімнаті, лиш серце так солодко *б'є*
   > Та вже *метнули* в битву козаки
   > Хлопчик бігає по луках, по гаях, *любує* квітками

#### Висновок

Фактично, склалася ситуація, коли показник `-ся` використовується не лише у первісному значенні, а і для позначення багатьох інших функцій, сенсів.

Тому не варто розглядати його формально, лише як замінник/скорочення слова «себе».

---

#### Література

1. Юрій Шевельов-Шерех — Нарис сучасної української літературної мови. Мюнхен: Молоде життя, 1951 — [djvu 1](http://chtyvo.org.ua/authors/Sheveliov_Yurii/Narys_suchasnoi_ukrainskoi_literaturnoi_movy/), [djvu 2](http://diasporiana.org.ua/movoznavstvo/1060-shereh-yu-naris-suchasnoyi-ukrayinskoyi-literaturnoyi-movi/)
2. Гінзбург М. — Правила вживання ся-дієслів у фахових українських текстах, 2016 — [Web](http://tc.terminology.lp.edu.ua/TK_Wisnyk842/TK_wisnyk842_1_ginzburg.htm)
3. [Чи є пасивні дієслівні конструкції питомими для української мови?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/1220/8)

Comment: Почитав (але ще не все) і зрозумів, що це більше схоже на бездумне зловживання -ся, бо без нього краще в тих випадках, де йде всупереч логіки, якщо вважати -ся як себе. Мене беруть (суб'єктивні, але достатні) сумніви щодо якості наведених джерел. Бо переважно висновки про те, що так можна використовувати ґрунтують на основі збору інформації, що десь хтось так робив, але не розглядають причини, мету і правильність такого використання. Проблема в тому, що важко довести зловживання чи правильність. Чи ні ... . Мені без -ся краще. Дякую за відповідь.

Comment: Розумію ваш розпач; мені також більше подобаються логічно зважені мови. Але маю і хороші новини. (1) Усі натуральні мови проходять шлях розвитку і **змінюються**. Якийсь фактор, спочатку будучи логічним, може змінитися до невпізнаваності. (2) Лише штучні мови (як-то Lojban) не мають таких недоліків.

Comment: (3) Є два підходи до аналізу (у даному випадку, аналізу морфології частки `-ся`) — [**дескриптивний і прескриптивний**](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/437/8). Наша мова — натуральна, і тому її варто розглядати *дескриптивно*, тобто, такою, яка вона є фактично. *Саме на основі збору інформації*, а не, наприклад, циркулярів напівграмотних монархів, як це ставалося у залісців. В яких вживання показника `-ся` настільки спотворене, що вони вже майже 300 років у масі своїй не можуть грамотно вживати `-тся` versus `-ться`. ;-)

Comment: Щодо описового методу можна зробити висновок, що такий метод не може стверджувати, що слово мною буде застосоване неправильно, якщо для створення опису слова не використано мого випадку використання слова.