# Difference between вчити, вчитися, вивчати?

Tags: різниця-між-словами, non-native-speaker

What's the difference between the words вчити, вчитися, and вивчати?  As far as I can tell they all mean "to learn" - are they just synonyms or is there more to it? In particular I don't understand what the ся suffix is doing if it doesn't change the meaning of the word - that seems linguistically confusing...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is one great question! The verb *вчити* acts as an [antagonym (contranym, auto-antonym)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auto-antonym) — a word that has two different meanings, merely opposite to each other.

- *Вчити*

  - + object-[ACC](https://#) — *to teach (someone)*

  > *я вчу дитину бути доброю* — I teach a kid to be kind;

  - + object-[ACC](https://#) — *to study (something)*

  > *я вчу українську мову* — I study Ukrainian language;

  - + object-[GEN](https://#) — *to teach (something)*

  > *я вчу української мови* — I teach Ukrainian language
- *Навчати*

  - + object-[GEN](https://#) — *to teach (something)*

  > *я навчаю української мови* — I teach Ukrainian language
- *Вчитися*, *навчатися*

  - (as a reflexive/intransitive verb) — *to study* (in general)
  - + a object-[DAT](https://#) — *to learn (something)*

  Both meanings (reflexive and transitive) present in a famous Shevchenko verse:

  > ***Учітесь**¹, читайте,*
  > *І чужому **научайтесь**,*
  > *Й свого не цурайтесь.*

  > *Gain knowledge, brothers! Think and read,*
  > *And to your neighbours' gifts pay heed, --*
  > *Yet do not thus neglect your own*
  > (My Friendly Epistle translated by C.H. Andrusyshen & W. Kirkconnel)
- *Вивчати*

  - + object-[ACC](https://#) — *to learn, to research (something)*

  > *я вивчаю українську мову* — I study Ukrainian language
  > *я вивчаю космос* — I research the space.

---

> In particular I don't understand what the ся suffix is doing if it doesn't change the meaning of the word - that seems linguistically confusing...

Generally, the `-ся` suffix indicates one of the following:

- an action directed to the subject itself (reflexive verb) (*митися* — to wash oneself);
- the absence (or the impossibility) of an object of an action;
- the mutuality of an action (*вітатися* — to greet; *одружуватися* — to marry, *битися* — to fight);
- subjectless phrases (only an object is specified);
- words that do not have a form with no `-ся` (*намагатися* — to try).

Well, as a language learner you should keep in mind that every language has many exceptions (that may look weird and illogical). I would suggest simply memorize them on a case-by-case basis first. With more practice, the proper form will come to your mind intuitively.

We have a question on this matter here (in Ukrainan),but I'm afraid I'm unable to translate my answer to a decent English. :)

- [Ну то -ся чи не -ся?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/6163/)

---

¹) I hope you are already familiar with the `у / в` [euphony](https://www.ukrainianlessons.com/euphony-in-ukrainian/).

Comment: Great thorough answer, thank you! :)  A lot of overlapping options, but you're right that languages are just like that and I'll get used to it with time.  (And yes, I knew about the у/в thing although I didn't know what it was called.) Thank you for the other question link too! I will attempt to make my way through the Ukrainian, the practice should do me good. :)