# Чому правильно писати «5000 українців було інтерновано» а не «5000 українців були інтерновані»?

Tags: граматика

Адже в реченні використовується множина а не не однина середнього роду. Я звик по-моєму до другого варіанта в російській. Але може і в ній це неправильно. Хтось знає детальніше про правила у випадках коли говориш про те що сталося з істотами в минулому? Дякую!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Були* — пасивна особова конструкція.

*Було* — пасивна безособова.

Якщо йдеться про наявність активного суб'єкта (інтерновано *ким?*), то вважається більш правильним використання активної конструкції — див, напр., дискусію на сторінці [Вікіпедія: Безособові форми на -но, -то: Помилки у вживанні безособових форм на -но, -то](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8_%D0%BD%D0%B0_-%D0%BD%D0%BE,_-%D1%82%D0%BE#%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D1%83_%D0%B2%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%96_%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%85_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC_%D0%BD%D0%B0_-%D0%BD%D0%BE,_-%D1%82%D0%BE)

Якщо активного суб'єкта нема, то обидві правильні, але безособова форма виглядає більш доречною з огляду на її упізнаваність серед слов'янських мов.

---

### Чтиво

- [Чи є пасивні дієслівні конструкції питомими для української мови?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/1220/)