# Як по-людськи перекласти українською "принятие ванны"?

Tags: переклад, from-russian

Російськомовний вислів нарочито формальний, тож не дивно, що у мовній практиці адекватного відповідника нема.
Та, може, я помиляюся і він все ж є?

Answer (score 3):

Нема поважних **лінгвістичних** причин вважати це словосполучення запозиченим з московського «русского язика». Англійські словосполучення *take a bath* та *have a bath* є цілком словниковими, нарівні з дієсловами *to bath* та *to bathe*.

З огляду на це, вживання словосполучень *приймати/брати ванну/душ* виглядає обґрунтованим.

---

Нема поважних **соціокультурних** причин вважати, що предмети побуту, пов'язані з миттям, прийшли з північно-східних боліт; радше навпаки. :)

*Ванна* походить від німецького *Wanne*, а *душ* споріднено зі словом ***дощ*** і має безліч еквівалентів у європейських мовах, як-то німецьке *Dusche*, італійське *doccia* або французьке *douche*.

---

Але я так розумію, вас найбільше цікавить обґрунтованість вживання слова «приймати».

[Пасивні дієслівні конструкції не є питомими для української мови](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/1220/8).
У даному випадку, щоправда, суб'єкт і об'єкт дії не міняються місцями.

Сайт «Мова — ДНК нації» має [сторінку про слово *приймати*](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/blog/dieslovo-prujmatu-pravula-vzhuvannya), де для багатьох випадків запропоновано саме активні форми дієслів.
Випадок *приймати ванну/душ* у статті не обговорюється, але присутній у коментарях, де читачі згадують про словосполучення **брати купіль** у Лесі Українки.
Я знайшов цю цитату у СУМ [до статті *«наглядати»*](http://sum.in.ua/s/naghljadaty):

> *Так ви наглянете, щоб ваша небога **брала купелі** регулярно і щоб увечері пізно не засиджувалась (Леся Українка, II, 1951, 66);*

Comment: Ну тобто "брати ванну". 
Дякую. 
Хай там як, вислів "брати ванну" вважаю прийнятним.

Comment: Щоб позначити відповідь «прийнятою», треба натиснути зелену кнопку-«галочку» під кнопками голосування. І ще має сенс зняти голос «мінус», ага. :))

Comment: "Брати ванну/душ" — ні, це жахливо, наприклад: *Він брав ванну [, але так і не повернув її].* А от "приймати ванну/душ" часто можна почути.